# Show that if $f(2n) \le Cf(n)$ for large enough $n$, where $f:N \to N$. Then $f(n)$ is asymtotically bounded by a polynomial?

Tags: computational-complexity

> Show that if $f(2n) \le Cf(n)$ for large enough $n$, where $f:N \to N$. Then $f(n)$ is bounded by a polynomial?

Some suggestions? I tried using the Master theorem but I didn't get some convincent.

Comment: I assume that you mean "then $f(n)$ is bounded by a polynomial." The single variable $n$ is already bounded by a polynomial, since it is one. :)

Comment: Yes, I already fixed it

Comment: OK. You fixed it. Now it's just false (as Robert Israel's example shows). Sigh.

Comment: But, for this function there is not a C satisficing the condition.

Comment: Sure there is: it's $C = 1$. Because $f(2n)$ will always be $f$ applied to an *even* number, and for every even number $2n$, $f(2n) = 1 \le C f(n)$, since $C = 1$ and $f(n)$ is at least $1$.

Comment: @Raffaele: what does $n/2$ mean when $n$ is an odd integer?  (Notice that $f$ is defined to be from $N$ to $N$.)

Answer (score 3):

Try $$ f(n) = \cases{n! & if $n$ is odd\cr 1 & if $n$ is even} $$